# Prevent "Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center" from installing

Tags: windows-7, mouse

Normally I use my laptop at the docking station. There I have an older optical mouse that is unfortunately no longer in production.

When I use my laptop in the living room I attach another mouse ("Comfort Mouse 4500") to it.

Whenever I do that, an auto-installation routine commences with a window declaring that the "Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center" is downloading (and eventually will be installed).

Naturally I cancel this as I don't need the advertised features and the mouse works perfectly fine in its capacity as a generic HID device as detected and support by Windows. In short, I consider it bloat that I don't want or need.

**NB:** in some cases, but not always, the aborted installation leaves a trace in form of a `Install Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center.lnk` on the desktop.

How can I prevent/block Windows (or whatever other component is responsible) from commencing an automatic installation process for the "Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center".

Comment: Does this installation process happen on any device you connect the mouse to?

Comment: @Ramhound: at least on two Windows machines it's the case, yes. One the aforementioned laptop.

Comment: Yes, it is very annoying! I get the same on an old MS Wheel Mouse. If you cancel the installation it generally gives up and doesn't do it again - at least for a while.

Comment: @JulianKnight: it doesn't do it in that "session", but after the device got disconnected and reconnected, I get it again.

Comment: Odd, it doesn't do that on my w8.1 machines.

Answer (score 0):

Use method two of this document: http://www.wikihow.com/Block-an-Application-or-.EXE-from-Running-in-Windows

You should be able to find the exe which is running the next time it happens, use that to block the application! Hope this helps.

If that doesn't work, look in to the Device Installation settings in the following branch of gpedit:

[image: 1]